# How to Slice ONNXRuntime Tensor?

Tags: c#, tensor, onnx, onnxruntime

Assume that a Microsoft.ML.Onnxruntime.Tensors.Tensor variable has been created with dimensions `[d1, d2, d3]`.  Is there a way to return a copy or view of a slice over certain dimensions?  I wanted to do the equivalent of `subset = inputs[start_idx:start_idx+batch_size, :, :]`, but ended up having to create a new tensor and copy in each value one-by-one.

```
var subset = new DenseTensor<float>(new[] {
batch_size, inputs.Dimensions[1], inputs.Dimensions[2]});

var start_idx = bidx * batch_size;
// create the input vector on a subset of the full batch
// inputs[start_idx:start_idx+batch_size, :, :] in python
for (int ridx = 0; ridx < batch_size; ++ridx)
{
    for (int cidx = 0; cidx < inputs.Dimensions[1]; ++cidx)
    {
        subset[ridx, cidx, 0] = inputs[start_idx + ridx, cidx, 0];
    }
}
```

The `[]` operator for a tensor can accept a sequence of integers as shown in this example, and also a ReadOnlySpan, but I couldn't figure out how to get these to do what I wanted.